# It is possible to run a chrome extension as a proxy server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, browser-extension

I am thinking of a browser extension that helps users to monitor website changes. This type of operation needs infrastructure for HTTP(S) requests.

I am wondering if can I build this network with all installed extensions. It's like crowd supported system. So every user will help the network by executing some requests(from others).

I found a related question, but I think the question is not clear enough:

[Is it possible to use Google Chrome as a proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028244/is-it-possible-to-use-google-chrome-as-a-proxy-server)

Comment: Not possible. You'll have to use an external server or an external program.

Comment: I see that you can use fetch in extensions so I think you could get an URL from a remote endpoint and fetch the source and send it again to that remote endpoint

Comment: A "server" is "remote endpoint".

Comment: yes, I used "remote endpoint" with the meaning of a central server.

Comment: Then the server will be a proxy, not the extension.

Comment: The server will use the extension as a proxy: 

1. The extension will request URLs needed to be resolved(from the server)
2. The extension will resolve the URL
3. The extension will send back to the server the response for the given URL

This is not how a regular proxy works it is more like a pull-push worker mechanism

Comment: That's word play. An extension can't be a server in the established meaning of the term.